# gfortran and ifort gives different results

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, fortran95

I am making a small code that will read numbers from 2.txt which is bunch of random real numbers, save it in a 2d array and pass it on the information to a subroutine. In the subroutine, I am assigning a particular dimension of this array to another matrix to save this for future calculation.

```
   implicit none
   double precision, allocatable :: x1(:,:)
   integer :: nstep, nheatoms, k, i, j
   open(unit=999,file="2.txt",status="old")

   nstep = 5
   nheatoms = 2

   allocate(x1(3,nheatoms))
   do k = 1, nstep
   do i = 1, 3
   do j = 1, nheatoms
   read(999,*) x1(i,j)
   end do
   read(999,*)
   end do
   call diffusion(nstep,nheatoms,x1)
   end do

   stop
   end

  subroutine diffusion(nstep,nheatoms,qhecent)
  implicit none
  integer, intent (in) :: nheatoms, nstep
  double precision :: qhecent(3,nheatoms)
  integer :: j
  double precision, allocatable  :: qhestep(:,:)
  integer :: nstepdiff, ncross
  integer, save :: l = 0
  double precision :: diff

  l = l + 1
   allocate(qhestep(nstep,nheatoms))
  do j = 1, nheatoms
  qhestep(l,j) = qhecent(3,j)
  end do

  if (l .gt. 1) then
  do j = 1, nheatoms
  write(*,*)qhestep(l,j), qhestep(l-1,j)
  end do
  end if
  end subroutine
```

The 2.txt file is as follows:

```
1.0
2.1

3.2
-1.1

-2.2
-3.3

5.0
3.5

4.4
1.9

2.1
1.5

6.0
3.5

4.4
1.9

2.8
2.5

6.0
3.5

4.4
1.9

2.1
3.2

6.0
3.5

4.4
1.9

-4.3
7.9
```

Now if I compile with gfortran, most of the time I obtain the output as:

```
   2.1000000000000001       -2.2000000000000002     
   1.5000000000000000       -3.2999999999999998     
   2.7999999999999998        2.1000000000000001     
   2.5000000000000000        1.5000000000000000     
   2.1000000000000001        2.7999999999999998     
   3.2000000000000002        2.5000000000000000     
  -4.2999999999999998        2.1000000000000001     
   7.9000000000000004        3.2000000000000002
```

which is expected. But if I run the code several times, an unknown number appear in the output, such as the example:

```
   2.1000000000000001       -2.2000000000000002     
   1.5000000000000000       -3.2999999999999998     
   2.7999999999999998        1.2882297539194267E-231
   
   2.5000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   2.1000000000000001        2.7999999999999998     
   3.2000000000000002        2.5000000000000000     
  -4.2999999999999998        2.1000000000000001     
   7.9000000000000004        3.2000000000000002
```

If I compile with ifort, then I obtain the output that have two zeros, which is wrong.

```
   2.10000000000000       -2.20000000000000     
   1.50000000000000       -3.30000000000000     
   2.80000000000000       0.000000000000000E+000

   2.50000000000000       0.000000000000000E+000

   2.10000000000000        2.80000000000000     
   3.20000000000000        2.50000000000000     
  -4.30000000000000        2.10000000000000     
   7.90000000000000        3.20000000000000
```

I must stress that compiling on ifort most of the time gives correct results as in the case for gfortran. I am on a Mac OS High Sierra.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the file `2.txt` (and not as an image). What do you mean by "But if just the code several time". Which compilation flags (and compiler versions) are you using. Smells a bit like not initialized variables.

Comment: "But if just the code several time": sorry a typo. Should be "But if just run the code several times".

Comment: @albert I am not using any compilation flags. For gfortran I am using version 6.3.0 and for ifort I am using 18.0.2.

Comment: Example crashes straight away when I compile. Best is to first start to check whether or not the input is what you expect it to be. the statement `read(999,*) x1(i,j)` reads a complete line and just stores the first element of the line. The line `read(999,*)` is not needed. Maybe `qhestep` should be initialized, but also check the indices you use.

Comment: remark regarding read statement is only valid with the first version of the first version of the input file, with the edited version (one value per line and a separation line) the read statements look OK.

Comment: Maybe a global `qhestep` instead of a local `qhestep` or a local save `qhestep` might do some good things.

Comment: @albert yes, locally saving the qhestep indeed solved the problem. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both compilers should give garbage results, as you are allocating qhestep in diffusion for each DO k loop. On exiting diffusion, qhestep is deallocated, so the accumulated information should be lost. That ifort returns the same heap address for qhestep on each call is misleading.

To overcome the problem, you should use allocate (qhestep(nstep,nheatoms)) before entering the DO k loop, then transfer the accumulation array in call diffusion.

That ifort gives your expected result is unfortunate, as it disguises a significant logic error. Each ALLOCATE basically provides a new memory location for the array.

You also provide no error tests when reading the file. I would recommend using iostat= for the reads and also report the data as it is read.

In summary, your approach gives the wrong result, which both compilers provide. The ifort results you provided are also wrong in some cases, but correct in others, which is misleading.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, if I allocate qhestep in the main program and pass it on to the subroutine diffusion, then the code is working fine in both ifort and gfortran. If I also locally save the qhestep in the subroutine diffusion, then it also works as expected, as suggested by albert.